# EC ElGamal versus static+ephemeral ECDH

Tags: protocol-design, elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, key-exchange, elgamal-encryption

A client application needs to encrypt a UDP datagram for a server with known EC public key $P$. Performing a full ECDH key exchange would defeat the benefit of using UDP as a connectionless protocol. I am therefore looking at ways to share a temporary symmetrical key decided by the client only.

Two solutions to that constraint seem to be :

- Generating an ephemeral key pair $(k,K)$, and encrypt the payload with $kP$ − **ECDH**.
- Generating a random key $r$ and encrypt it with **[EC ElGamal](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9987/elgamal-with-elliptic-curves)**.

The ECDH approach requires **1 EC multiplication** from the client ($kP$), **1 EC point** to include in the datagram ($K$), and **1 EC multiplication** from the server ($pK$).

According to the link above, the EC ElGamal approach seems to require **2 EC multiplications** from the client, **2 EC points** to include in the datagram, and **1 EC multiplication** from the server.

*Diffie-Hellman is apparently lighter in computation and header data. What is the advantage of using ElGamal ?*

Comment: You may look at [this related question/answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11752/elliptic-curve-encryption-ciphertext-size/11755#11755).

Comment: I do not get your ECDH scheme; how does the server recover the symmetric key?

Comment: What I referred to as static-ephemeral ECDH is effectively what is called ECIES. Thanks @DrLecter for clarifying.

I still cannot find much benefit in using ElGamal for key sharing. I see mentions of homomorphism and malleability, which are of little use for this purpose.

Answer (score 8):

ElGamal appears to be used instead of Diffie-Hellman (or [IES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme)) in [OpenPGP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) mostly because when that format was put together, there were some unresolved intellectual property issues surrounding both RSA and Diffie-Hellman, while ElGamal was unproblematic. This trend for ElGamal seems to stick around, mostly by force of habit, e.g. when switching to elliptic-curve variants.

If you look at ElGamal closely, you will see that it is, in fact, a Diffie-Hellman key exchange, where the resulting key is used to encrypt a message in a kind of one-time-pad system (the $y^r$ value is the DH output, and is combined, using the group operation, with the message to encrypt). Using the group operation allows for homomorphism, but when that property is not needed, it is a useless complication and overhead.

Comment: ElGamal is a DH key exchange where the recipient has a fixed DH message (the public key), and the key is used to encrypt the message using a one-time shift cipher. ECIES is a DH key exchange where the recipient has a fixed DH message (the public key), and the key is used to encrypt the message using a secure one-time symmetric cryptosystem.